# Get property by reflection and set its subproperty

Tags: c#, class

I have to find in the `featuresHome` class a property through a string (done through: `var property = typeof (featuresHome) .GetProperty ("homePosition");`) afterwards I have to set the `positionLake` property of the `homePosition`.

Code:

```
class Home
{
    public featuresHome FeaturesHome { get; set; }
}

class featuresHome
{
    public homePosition HomePosition { get; set; }
    public homeKind HomeKind { get; set; }
}

class homePosition
{
    public string PositionLake { get; set; }
    public string PositionDowntown { get; set; }
}

class homeKind
{
    public string HomeFlat { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string HomeVilla { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

class Program
{
    static List<Home> HomeList = new List<Home>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HomeList.Add(new Home());

        featuresHome FeaturesHome = HomeList.Last().FeaturesHome;
        var property = typeof(featuresHome).GetProperty("homePosition");
        property.SetValue(FeaturesHome.HomePosition.PositionLake, "Mono Lake", null); //Here there is an error
    }
}
```

The goal is to find the property of the "featuresHome" class through a string and then set the value of a property ("PositionLake")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is reflection needed? Sounds like a XY problem http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: You probably want a `Dictionary<string, string>`; if you explained [what you are trying to accomplish instead of what you are doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) we may be able to help.

Comment: Sounds very much like a homework exercise to me. I can think of no other reason why one would want to use reflection in this scenario at all....

Comment: FYI: In C# it is common practice to have class/type names starting with an upper-case letter (PascalCase style), while (local) variable names start with a lower-case letter (camelCase style). At several places there in your code, you did it the other way round. Doing so is very unusual and has the quite likely potential to cause confusion in others, as well as in yourself in some near future... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
featuresHome FeaturesHome = HomeList.Last().FeaturesHome;
var property = typeof(featuresHome).GetProperty("homePosition");
```

Just get its `HomePosition` property:

```
property.SetValue(FeaturesHome.HomePosition.PositionLake, "Mono Lake", null);
HomePosition hp = new HomePosition {PositionLake = "Mono Lake"}
```

Then set `HomePosition` property of FeaturesHome:

```
property.SetValue(FeaturesHome, hp, null);
```

Comment: return an error in part second of your code: featuresHome is a type, which is not valid in the specified context (HomePosition hp = property.GetValue(featuresHome);)

Comment: well it was it was just because of typo `featuresHome` instead of `FeaturesHome`. now it must work. check it

Comment: Now on the third line of code returns this error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Reference to an object not set on an object instance.' property was null.  (property.SetValue(FeaturesHome.HomePosition.PositionLake, "Mono Lake", null);)

Comment: @Rio, what do you think the value of `Home.FeaturesHome` is there in the `Home` object inside your home list? ;-)

Comment: It always returns the error on line three : (property.SetValue(FeaturesHome.HomePosition.PositionLake, "Mono Lake", null);)

Comment: @Rio, you will know why that error happens, if you you would just look what the value of the `FeaturesHome` property of the `Home` object in your HomeList is. What is its value?

Comment: Even implementing these two properties gives me the same error. (HomeList.Last (). FeaturesHome = new featuresHome ();
             HomeList.Last (). FeaturesHome.HomePosition = new homePosition ();)

Comment: @Rio, the code in the answer has errors, and you cannot just copy&paste the code and hope everything is fine and dandy. Note how the code in the current version of the answer gets a PropertyInfo object (`property` variable) for a property of the `featuresHome` type. But then this very same PropertyInfo object (representing a `featuresHome` property) is used to set a property of the `homePosition` type (the type of the instance given by `FeaturesHome.HomePosition.PositionLake`). Yeah, no...

Comment: @Rio, you already know the names of reflection methods involved in getting and setting a property through reflection. I suggest you spend some time reading the documentation regarding these methods (what they do exactly, what the exact purpose of their method arguments is, and how the methods use the method arguments provided to them etc...), and perhaps also spend some time with some tutorials/guides covering reflection.

Comment: @Rio, did you just read up on the documentation in just the last couple seconds before writing your comment? Man, you are quick ;-) No, what i was writing in my last comment was meant sincerly. Spend some time with the documentation, do not expect other people to do your homework for you. Learning to code is just partially writing code. Most time will be spend reading; a lot before and while coding, and a lot more during troubleshooting of the program ;-)

Comment: I think I asked a question and expected an answer. is what the site expects.

Comment: @Rio, well, read [ask]. Notice what is written there right at the beginning? "Seach and **research**". This site is not about asking questions without doing due research first. But that's just my opionion. I will not block or otherwise hinder anyone wanting to answer your question with code for copy&paste, if they so desire (not that i could block or hinder anyone from anything here, anyway ;-P). Chances are that someone will come and just offer copy&paste solution. It's a bit based on luck, but also not that uncommon here...

Comment: I have no desire to write a program but simply a question.